# how do i run a script when the cpu gets too hot

Tags: gpio, led, temperature, hat, safety

i need to send commands to my hats that control fans and a little warning LED if the cpu goes above or below a specified state of temperature

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/756721/raspberry-pi-specific-script-to-run-commands-upon-cpu-reaching-defined-temperatu is the original post that should explain what i'm trying to do

i know there are physical means to control the temps but i want fans turned on and off depending on the temperature of the pi

Comment: This seems to be a how do I write a program question which is not a suitable question here.

Answer (score 0):

For the temperature monitoring part, use
[this](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/temperature-log/1) tutorial. I don't know how to control the fans without knowing the hat type.

Comment: it's just a dockerpi relay hat i have a 12 volt rail for that relay to power a fan and a led. i managed to find someone who helped me put something together in python